# Multiplication of a uniformly random permutation and a random permutation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have some uniformly random permutation $\sigma$ and $\tau$ which is a random permutation that is independent of $\sigma$. Is it true that $\sigma$$\tau$ is also uniformly random?

I'm having some difficulty seeing if this is true. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. More generally, for any finite group $G$, if you take a uniformly randomly selected element $g\in G$ and multiply it (from left or right) with some $h\in G$, no matter how it’s generated (fixed or random, not necessarily uniform), the result is again a uniformly randomly selected element of $G$. That’s because group multiplication is a bijection, so each $g'\in G$ has exactly one equiprobable $g\in G$ mapped to it, so the $g'$ are again equiprobable.